# Apachectl command does not work properly on mac

Tags: macos, apache, terminal

I started learning Apache server with my macbook, and I typed apachectl on the Terminal.

Unfortunately I could only see the following message.

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Marshalls-MacBook-Air.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

What do you think is the matter, and how should I fix?

Comment: You are not running the process as the root user. Launch again using `sudo`

Comment: @arco444 I just tried that, and it showed another message - AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Marshalls-MacBook-Air.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (pid 5306) already running

Comment: There must be something wrong with the system configuration, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: They are both warnings, you can disregard them for the time being. At least that got rid of the `Permission denied` message. Something is already running Apache. Don't know how you installed it, but I'd imagine `launchd` runs it in the background, so you might need to use `launchctl` to stop it first

Answer (score 0):

> I typed `apachectl`

You need prefix `apachectl` with `sudo`, so:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

otherwise the command has no enough privileges to bind into port 80.

---

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

You need to edit your `httpd.conf` Apache configuration file and uncomment `ServerName` line.

To locate the file, run: `apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES` first.